# Check for specific formula (no VBA)

Tags: excel

Is it possible to check if cell formula is a specific formula, and not just "isformula" ?

My example:
In cell A1 I have, normally, *"=B2"*.
But during the use of this sheet the formula might be overwritten to *"=D4".*
How can I get a simple TRUE result if the formula in cell A1 is "=D4", and FALSE if it's something else ?

I get fix it with VBA but I prefer to use standard formulas first (if it's possible obviously).
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`FORMULATEXT`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/formulatext-function-0a786771-54fd-4ae2-96ee-09cda35439c8):

```
=FORMULATEXT(A1)="=D4"
```

[image]